# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have like error message : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

For my method index() I have this:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {   
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
         if($request->has('search'))
              $remarks = Remark::orderBy('instruction', 'asc')->where('instruction','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
         else
             $remarks = Remark::all();
    }else{
         \Auth::user()->load('remarks');
         $remarks = \Auth::user()->remarks;
    }

    return view('admin.remarks.index', compact('remarks'));
    }
```

Concerning my index.blade.php I have my loop "for" which is like this:

```
                <th>Instruction</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Date seance</th>
                <th>Name Candidate</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
               @foreach($remarks as $remark)
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$remark->instruction}}</td>
                   <td> {{$remark->description}}</td>
                   <td> {{$remark->seances->date_seance}}</td>
                   <td> {{$remark->seances()->first()->candidates->name}}</td>
                   <td> {{$remark->seances()->first()->candidates->email}}</td>
                   <td>
```

Do you have an idea of my problem please? I don't understand ??

Comment: Does the same error always returns?  I see that if the user has an admin role and there is a search, field in the request, you are only building the query but not executing it, so the foreach argument would be a query builder object and not a collection

Comment: @ porloscerros Ψ: When I connect with the role "administrator", I have another error message. "Method Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ Collection :: links does not exist."

Comment: for that case look at the Tharaka Dilshan answer, you have to add a get, or paginate to run the query. So, in none of the cases that vary according to the conditions does the foreach work? Are you using pagination links in the view?

Comment: Just for debug, what I would try to, would be to just return Remark::all(), if that doesn't work, none of the others will work, and the problem is elsewhere

Comment: @porloscerros Ψ: my problem is in my relationship, I have create a topic. it's more precise here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937237/my-models-and-my-relationships-on-laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `get()` after the Eloquent Query Builder to fetch the data from the database. Unless it's an Eloquent Query Builder Object (which is not iterable, so cannot be used in a for loop).

The function `get()` will return the result as a Laravel Collection (which is iterable).

```php
$remarks = Remark::orderBy('instruction', 'asc')
               ->where('instruction','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%')
               ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, but I always have the same message... I have do a `dd(remarks)` I have this like information -> null ????

Comment: I think `\Auth::user()->remarks;` returns null if you haven't defined the `remarks()` relationship on the `User` model.

Comment: Ah, ok my problem is in my model ... What do you think about my architecture and my models? Thank you => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57937237/my-models-and-my-relationships-on-laravel

Answer (score -1):

you should querying from database not from session and don't forgot define relations on users model :

on users model:

```
public function remarks(){
   return $this->hasMany(Remark:class)
}
```

on your controller

```
  public function index(Request $request)
    {   
    if(\Auth::user()->hasRole('admin')){
         if($request->has('search'))
              $remarks = Remark::orderBy('instruction', 'asc')->where('instruction','like','%'.$request->input('search').'%');
         else
             $remarks = Remark::all();
    }else{
         $user = Users::find(Auth::id());
         $remarks=$user->remarks
    }

    return view('admin.remarks.index', compact('remarks'));
    }
```